# Carry bit of python bitwise shift

Tags: python

Is there any way to get the bit that is shifted off by a shift operation in Python, like the carry flag in x86 assembly?

I searched both the python manual and the internet, but can't seem to find anything useful.

I need it to check if an integer is odd (CF=1) or even (CF=0) and divide it by two in one command. I know that I can mimic the intended behaviour by:

```
if x & 1==1: CF=1
else: CF=0
```

That seems to me as unnecessary coding, or am I expecting to much from python.

Comment: And what's wrong with `CF = x & 1`?

Comment: Oh..., didn't think of that. Woops. Still it feels like it should go with the shift instruction automatically. I'm so used to it now from my programming in assembly that I can't help to think it should be somewhere in a status flag already.

Comment: You don't often work with bit fields in Python, but when you do, it's not that unexpected to see code like `rest, cf = x>>1, x&1`.

Comment: so, you are saying that; yes, I am expecting to much of python =P.

Comment: @Erik: I guess you could put it that way. But you're wrong that it's probably somewhere in a status flag already. That is likely guaranteed true for mid-level languages like C, but it's probably _never_ true for most Python implementations.

Comment: @Erik: Also, keep in mind that not every platform is identical to x86. On a PowerPC 601, there are a variety of different combined-rot/shift/mask instructions, and the fastest way to rshift one bit actually _doesn't_ set the carry flag for you.

Comment: @Erik: Well, maybe, or rather you are expecting Python to be a different language. Python has some specific design decisions, and emphasizes readability, <personalOpinion>where doing `rest, cf = x >> 1, x & 1` fits better than doing that implicitly</personalOpinion>.

Comment: I've done allot of x86 assembly programming lately so I think in BIOS interrupts and status flags now. So probably I am unconsciously translating my python code into its x86 equivalent and thus expecting it to behave likewise. XD

Also I still, after quite some years of python experience, have a hard time grasping the idea behind some of the discussions that went into designing the python script, like the fact that you can't force a function variable to be imported as a raw string.

Comment: @Erik: I don't even know what that last part means. Variables are just variables; they don't have types. Functions are first-class objects; for a given function, there's no guarantee there even ever _was_ a string that it was built from—and, even if there was, the string wouldn't have all of the relevant information if there are any closure cells. And raw strings aren't a type of strings; raw string _literals_ are a type of string _literals_, but they specify the exact same kind of strings as regular string literals. And…

Comment: What I mean is that in BASIC you declare a function as `Function foo(a as string)`. If you than call foo(123), the 123 part is interpreted as "123" and is stored in 'a'. Yet in python 123 is interpreted as an int and thusly stored in 'a'.

Comment: @Erik: Well, BASIC is pretty far from x86 assembly. And you're using really confusing terminology; importing and matching arguments to parameters in a function call are on opposite sides of the languages. But more importantly, why do you need that feature? `a = str(a)` has the same effect, is more explicit, and takes exactly as many characters to type.

Comment: @abarnert:It doesn't have the same effect if you would call foo(1+x) or more complex formulas. I needed it for a plotter I was writing were I needed the full formula to be stored in the variable without interpretation and the errors of undefined variables that come with it. I now that you can enclose the formula in quotes but I don't like having to constantly type quotes, it slows down the typing significantly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no "shift and also return carry flag" operation in Python—or, really, in almost any higher-level language. Even in C, where `y = x >> 1` compiles to the exact same machine-language op you would have written manually, and you know the carry flag has what you want, there's no way to access it.

However, it's very easy to do this yourself. Instead of this:

```
rest = x>>1
cf = get_carry_flag()
```

… you do this:

```
rest, cf = x>>1, x&1
```

It's more compact—and probably faster, too. Remember, this is Python; `x>>1` isn't translating into a single bit-shift opcode, but into a sequence of bytecodes that the interpreter handles by calling a function that follows a pointer to a linked list representing an arbitrary-length integer and shifts that…

---

For shifting the other way, there *is* no overflow on left-shift, so you have to exclusively `%` off the top bit. Once you're doing that, remembering the top bit before discarding it isn't much extra burden.

Answer (score 0):

Shift left:

```
x,bit= x<<1, (x&128)>>7
```

Shift right:

```
x,bit= x>>1, x&1
```

every time you execute it, you get the high or low bit and the "x" shifts

```
>>> x=0x5a
>>>
>>>
>>> x,bit= x<<1, (x&128)>>7; bit 0
>>> x,bit= x<<1, (x&128)>>7; bit 1
>>> x,bit= x<<1, (x&128)>>7; bit 0
>>> x,bit= x<<1, (x&128)>>7; bit 1
>>> x,bit= x<<1, (x&128)>>7; bit 1
>>> x,bit= x<<1, (x&128)>>7; bit 0
>>> x,bit= x<<1, (x&128)>>7; bit 1
>>> x,bit= x<<1, (x&128)>>7; bit 0
```